# Python: Function from different class not running with thread

Tags: python, multithreading

Im trying to implement a gui for a script I have written.
The script itself runs perfectly fine but as soon as I try to run it using a thread, it will just freeze the whole process without any feedback.
The thread seems to not execute the function.

```
import Foo
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

class GUI():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.file = "path/file"
        self.key = "path/key"
        # init GUI
        ...
    def updateDev(self):
        fib = Foo.foo()
        
        pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
        async_res = pool.apply_async(fib.update, args=(self.file, self.key))
        async_res.wait() 
        # the code freezes here
        res = async_res.get()
        ...
```

Is there anything im missing?
`fib.update(self.file, self.key)` runs like this without any threads perfectly.

EDIT:
I solved it myself yesterday by adding a function that starts the thread.

```
import Foo
from threading import Thread

class GUI():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.file = "path/file"
        self.key = "path/key"
        # init GUI
        ...
    def startDev(self):
        t = Thread(target = self.updateDev)
        t.start()

    def updateDev(self):
        fib = Foo.foo()
        fib.update(self.file, self.key)
        ...
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Your question is more likely to be answered if you can post a [mre].

Comment: @khelwood thanks ill try to work on it but i think the given example shows the given problem. I try to run a function from a different class with a ThreadPool. Maybe the problem is that both classes have a function named update.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't understand what is the pourpose of the code. If I correctly understand, the code will never reach the `async_res.wait()` satement because it is recoursive. This row `async_res = pool.apply_async(fib.update, args=(self.file, self.key))` will probably run again the "update" function

Comment: I changed the name of the function in GUI to `updateDev`. This sadly did not change anything.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation at this link https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool and then to this https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply.
And try to add a debug code in the Foo class to understand if the code reach the function with the correct parameters.